# How to enable Reference Search View extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

Today in my colleague's vscode I saw that finding references opens in sidebar.

I searched the web and I understood that it's done by [Reference Search View](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.references-view#overview), an extension shipped by vscode but it's not working for me. How can I enable it?

```
Version: 1.30.2
Commit: 61122f88f0bf01e2ac16bdb9e1bc4571755f5bd8
Date: 2019-01-07T22:49:48.319Z
Electron: 2.0.12
Chrome: 61.0.3163.100
Node.js: 8.9.3
V8: 6.1.534.41
OS: Linux x64 4.15.0-43-generic
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

The issue was that I was using

`"command": editor.action.referenceSearch.trigger"`

instead of

`"command": "references-view.find"`

in my keybindings.

I'm actually pleased! because I can still have the old behaviour by using the first command :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a built-in extensions. It is included in VS Code 1.30+ and is enabled by default. Search `@builtin references` in the extension view to make sure you have not accidentally disabled it.

To show references, run the `References: Find all references` command. This should open the references sidebar with the reference results

Comment: I've already checked. It's not disabled and yet for no apparent reason it's not working! :(